# Node.js expressjs sessions don't stick in Firefox

Tags: session, node.js, cookies, express

I'm using express with nodejs and sessions don't stick in Firefox.  The work fine in Chrome however.

I have my maxAge to 14400000 which I've read could be an issue since my local machine is on GMT, but still it doesn't seem to stick.

This is what I have configured:

```
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mysecret', store: new RedisStore, cookie: { maxAge: 14400000 }}));
```

I'm setting it simply by doing:

```
req.session.user = 'something'
```

Any ideas what this could be?

Thank you!

Comment: if you query the db, I'm guessing it contains the sessions.

Comment: Dave same problem arise with me the firefox browser is loading infinitely if used express.session with mozilla while chrome is working fine.. have you find any reference?...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `req.session. regenerate(callback)` when you first establish the session. It would look something like this:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mysecret', store: new RedisStore, cookie: { maxAge: 14400000 }}));

var user = //Define your user

req.session.regenerate(function() {
   req.session.user = user;
   res.redirect('/loggedin');
});
```

Give it a try!

Comment: This will cause the session to be recreated for each page view.  I think this might be more of a workaround than a solution.  Gonna do some more searching myself.

Comment: Definitely a workaround, let me know if you find a better solution. (I'm honestly not sure if this problem even still exists).

Comment: I forgot about this. Ut oh... just checked and it's not in my code so it must've sorted itself out with an `npm update express` or something.

Comment: Haha no worries, glad it got sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

Without wasting time here is the fix:

```
app.use(
   session({
   httpOnly: false,
   secret: "top secret",
  })
 );
```

Now if you are interested in real story:

Mozilla is a strict browser. She play by the rules. If something is not working in Mozilla but in chrome its mean you are doing it wrong.
In production environment there we set https  . and by default express.session httpOnly is true, just make it false.
:) so it can also work on https.